# NumPy in Cython: compile-time type vs original type

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, cython

In Cython, there are corresponding compile-time types to NumPy. It seems that the compile-time type are faster than the original type. If we combine them with the C type, for example, there are three keywords that can be used to define a integer type: `int`, `np.int`, `np.int_t`.

In the [official tutorial](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/tutorial/numpy.html), all these three types are used. This makes me feel confused. Here are my questions:

Is it correct to use the sole data type to achieve a better performance? And, which type should I choose? If using the sole data type is not correct, then how should I determine which type to use in different parts of my program?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

The other answer is unfortunately partly right, and the Cython documentation looks like it's unfortunately partly outdated.

So there's essentially two contexts where you use Numpy types with Cython:

1. The are Python objects that can be passed to Numpy functions as a `dtype=` argument. These indicate to Numpy what type of array to create. From Cython's point of view they're the same as any other Python object. However, Numpy treats them as special indicators. `np.int` was an example of these (but has now been removed in favour of just using the normal Python `int`). Specificity sized integer dtypes like `np.int32` are still available though.

   ```
   arr = np.zeros((5,10), dtype=np.int)
   ```

   These are not Cython-specific. They're the same as you'd use in normal Python code.
2. The second use is as C integer types. `np.int_t` *does exist* (this is where the other answer is wrong). However, it's a C typedef that's only exposed in the [.pxd file that wraps the Numpy internals for Cython](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4cc5bd699c864bc3d52b353f6e0e2b5ee7f3a9c7/numpy/__init__.pxd#LL712C15-L712C15). They're what you `cimport` from Numpy, rather than what you `import` from Numpy.

   You use these types anywhere that a C type would be expected (e.g. `cdef int_t some_var` or `cdef int_t[:] some_memoryview`). They largely have the same name as the `dtypes` but with `_t` on the end.

As an example of how you'd combine the two, you can create a 2D memoryview, and allocate an array for it to view with the line

```
cdef np.int32_t[:,:] mview = np.zeros((5, 10), dtype=np.int32)
```

The plain `int` type has two meanings in Cython. It can be used as the normal Python integer object (e.g. you can pass it as a `dtype` argument). However, in other contexts Python interprets it as a C integer. Therefore you could do

```
cdef int[:,:] mview = np.zeros((5, 10), dtype=int)
```

and this would also work. The first use it's used as a C type. The second as a normal Python object.

It's slightly confusing because Cython straddles Python (where types are just Python objects like any other Python object) and C (where a type is used to declare a variable, but is not an object to be passed around in its own right) and it isn't always clear which bits are C-like and which bits are Python-like.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this tutorial is very outdated. NumPy doesn't have `int_t`, and `int` is deprecated (`np.int`, not `int`).

So I guess this answers the question on which of the int options to use. There's only `int`, which defaults to `np.int64` (at least on my machine, could maybe also be `np.int32`).

However, note that there are different size options for `int`, like `int32` and `int64`, which you may choose between if you know the size of the integers you wish to store.